# which is better, using a nullable or a boolean return+out parameter

Tags: c#, coding-style

Lets say I have a function that needs to return some integer value. but it can also fail, and I need to know when it does.

Which is the better way?

```
public int? DoSomethingWonderful()
```

or

```
public bool DoSomethingWonderful(out int parameter)
```

this is probably more of a style question, but I'm still curious which option people would take.

Edit: clarification, this code talks to a black box (lets call it a cloud. no, a black box. no, wait. cloud. yes). I dont care *why* it failed. I would just need to know if I have a valid value or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like the nullable version better, because you can use the null coalesce operator ?? on it, e.g.:

```
int reallyTerrible = 0;
var mightBeWonderful = DoSomethingWonderful() ?? reallyTerrible;
```

Comment: Just what I was going to write. It also means you don't need to declare a separate variable if you don't need it. Basically it allows for more fluid expressions.

Comment: WOW!!!! I just preempted Jon Skeet on an SO answer!!! I won't be able to sleep tonight!

Comment: This is really nice. It depends on how this null should be handled. Because of the "it can also fail" in the question, I assumed that it is an error and should not be ignored like this. If it can, this approach is definitely the best.

Comment: I really like this. which is why I accepted it as an answer, even though this question is open ended (and asks for an opinion, not a specific answer).

Answer (score 7):

**It depends on how you think the calling code should look like.** And therefore what your function is used for.

Generally, you should avoid out arguments. On the other hand, it could be nice to have code like this:

```
int parameter;
if (DoSomething(out paramameter))
{
  // use parameter
}
```

When you have a nullable int, it would look like this:

```
int? result = DoSomething();
if (result != null)
{
  // use result
}
```

This is somewhat better because you don't have an out argument, but the code that decides if the function succeeded doesn't look very obvious.

Don't forget that there is another option: use Exeptions. Only do this if the case where your function fails is really an exceptional and kind of a error-case.

```
try
{
  // normal case
  int result = DoSomething()
}
catch (SomethingFailedException ex)
{
  // exceptional case
}
```

One advantage of the exception is that you can't just ignore it. The normal case is also straight forward to implement. If the exceptional case something you could ignore, you shouldn't use exceptions.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention: another advantage of an Exception is that you also can provide information *why* the operation failed. This information is provided by the Exception type, properties of the Exception and the message text.

Comment: I've grown to try and avoid exceptions. I work in test automation and an accidentally unhandled exception by another engineer can result in a disaster. everybody gets testing for a valid return, but people often forget to catch :(

Comment: You probably don't need the `out` parameter in the `int?` case in your example; I assume that the value delivered in the `out` parameter in the first example is what is returned in the second.

Comment: @Oren: But if you forget to test for error-codes, a potential problem is ignored. Exceptions allow you to handle the problem in a higher level, for instance close a window, but not the client or whatever. I used to work with code having error codes, and it is what I call a disaster... I'm talking about errors, not about "just-no-value"-cases.

Comment: @Frederik: you're right, copy-paste error, just fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why not throw an exception?

Comment: Don't use exceptions if it's not REALLY exceptional.

Comment: But you do not know if it is exceptional or not, only the OP does.  Perhaps the OP should chime in; do you expect your method to fail in ordinary circumstances?  If not, the exception is the way to go.

Comment: I quote from the .NET design guidelines: "Exceptions are the standard mechanism for reporting errors. Applications and libraries should not use return codes to communicate errors."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229014(VS.80).aspx

Comment: If it's for reporting a failure, I think it's safe to assume it's an exceptional case.  I don't think I've ever seen a function call for which it was unusual for it to not-fail.  :-)

Comment: Exceptions are to be used for conditions the caller is not prepared to handle.  It is often useful to allow a caller to indicate whether or not it is prepared to handle certain conditions (e.g. by calling TryGetValue rather than GetValue).  The original question here is how a method should notify a caller that a value couldn't be retrieved in cases where the caller is prepared for that.

Answer (score 2):

I would follow the pattern used in some place in the .Net library like:

```
bool int.TryParse(string s, out value)
bool Dictionary.TryGetValue(T1 key, out T2 value)
```

So I would say:

```
public bool TryDoSomethingWonderful(out int parameter)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the second, because I probably need to know right away if the call succeeded, and in that case I would rather write

```
int x;
if( DoSomethingWonderful( out x ) )
{
    SomethingElse(x);
}
```

than

```
int? x = DoSomethingWonderful();
if( x.HasValue )
{
   SomethingElse(x.Value);
}
```

Comment: To make your code snippets comparable you should declare x in the first snippet too.

Comment: Actually, you would need to declare the x variable prior to use in the first example, so the number of lines of code will be the same.

Comment: Well, that might be because you're comparing to weird usage. How about `if (x != null) { SomethingElse((int)x); }`?

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you are doing.

Is null a meaningful answer?  If not, I would prefer a `bool TryDoSomethingWonderful(out int)` method call.  This matches up with the Framework.

If, however, null is a meaningful return value, returning int? makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Unless performance is the primary concern you should return an `int` and throw an exception on failure.

Answer (score 1):

I am in favor of using an output parameter.  In my opinion, this is the kind of situation for which use of an output parameters is most suited.

Yes, you can use the coalesce operator to keep your code as a one-liner if and only if you have an alternative value that you can use in the rest of your code.  I often find that is not the case for me, and I would prefer to execute a different code path than I would if I was successfully able to retrieve a value.

```
        int value;
        if(DoSomethingWonderful(out value))
        {
            // continue on your merry way
        }
        else
        {
            // oops
            Log("Unable to do something wonderful");

            if (DoSomethingTerrible(out value))
            {
                // continue on your not-so-merry way
            }
            else
            {
                GiveUp();
            }
        }
```

Additionally, if the value that I want to retrieve is actually nullable, then using a function with an output parameter and a boolean return value is, in my opinion, the easiest way to tell the difference between "I was unsuccessful in retrieving the value" and "The value I retrieved is null".  Sometimes I care about that distinction, such as in the following example:

```
    private int? _Value;
    private bool _ValueCanBeUsed = false;

    public int? Value
    {
        get { return this._Value; }
        set
        {
            this._Value = value;
            this._ValueCanBeUsed = true;
        }
    }

    public bool DoSomethingTerrible(out int? value)
    {
        if (this._ValueCanBeUsed)
        {
            value = this._Value;
            // prevent others from using this value until it has been set again
            this._ValueCanBeUsed = false;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            value = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my opinion, the only reason most people tend not to use output parameters is because they find the syntax cumbersome.  However, I really feel that using output parameters is the more appropriate solution to this problem, and I found that once I got used to it I found the syntax much preferable to returning a null value.

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one way it can fail, or if you'll never need to know *why* it failed, I'd say it's probably simpler and easier to go with the nullable return value.

Conversely, if there are multiple ways it could fail, and the calling code could want to know exactly why it failed, then go with the out parameter and return an error code instead of a bool (alternatively, you could throw an exception, but based on your question, it seems you've already decided not to throw an exception).

Answer (score 0):

You should rather then use a try catch. This seems like the caller does not know what might happen?

Should we check both bool and the out, or should i check both returns null and the actual return.

Let the method do what it should, and in the case where it failed, let the caller know that it failed, and the caller hanlde as requied.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, my personal opinion sways significantly based on the nature of the method. Specifically, if the method's purpose is to *retrieve a single value*, as opposing to "doing something".

Ex:

```
bool GetSerialNumber(out string serialNumber)
```

vs

```
string GetSerialNumber() // returns null on failure
```

The second feels more "natural" to me somehow, and likewise:

```
bool GetDeviceId(out int id)
```

vs

```
int? GetDeviceId() // returns null on failure`
```

But I admit this really falls into "coding style" territory.

Oh, and I, too, would tend to favor exception throwing:

```
int GetDeviceId() // throws an exception on read failure
```

I'm still not sold on why they'd be so wrong. Can we have a thread on that, Oren? ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744070/why-should-exceptions-be-used-conservatively

Answer (score 0):

I dislike Microsoft's "Try" pattern in which the "out" parameter is used to return a data item.  Among other things, methods coded in that fashion cannot be used in covariant interfaces.  I would rather see a method coded as: `T GetValue(out bool Successful)` or perhaps `T GetValue(out GetValueErrorEnum result);` or `T GetValue(out GetValueErrorInfo result);` if something beyond a true/false might be needed.  Since every data type has a legal default value, there's no problem with deciding what to return if the function fails.  Calling code can easily say:

```
  bool success;
  var myValue = Thing.GetValue(ref success);
  if (success)
    .. do something using myValue
  else
    .. ignore myValue
```

It would be nice if .net and C# offered true covariant 'copy out' parameters (the caller would allocate space for the result, pass a pointer to that space to the called function, and then copy the allocated space to the passed-in variable only after the function returned).