# Return value or out parameter for c# method that can return either a char or string?

Tags: c#, coding-style, out-parameters

I ran across some code during a code review that didn't seem right, but not sure the "best" way to change it. In looking for an a answer I found [which is better, using a nullable or a boolean return+out parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800003/which-is-better-using-a-nullable-or-a-boolean-returnout-parameter) and [Which is better, return value or out parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810797/which-is-better-return-value-or-out-parameter)  The latter had a answer with this comment that I generally agree with:

> If you find yourself needing to return two things from an API then wrapping them up in a struct/class would be better than an out param."

Here is a representative sample of the code in question.  It's part of a web application and  basically loops through a character buffer and wants to translate "unprintable" characters to either a replacement character or string.  To do this, the author of the `Translate` method always returns a string and the caller has to convert back to a character array.

```
string character = Translate(value);
if (character.Length == 1) {
    writer.Write(character[0]);
} else {
    writer.Write(character.ToCharArray());
}

public string Translate(char value) {
    if (value <= '\u017F') {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    switch (value) {
        case '\u2117':
            return '\u00A9'.ToString();  // copyright sign
        case '\u211E':
            return "Rx"; // prescription
        // ... and lots more case statements
    }

    return value.ToString();
}
```

It seemed to me I have a couple options.  Do I make the caller infer which char or string to use based on null or String.Empty values, or be explicit with an out bool?  I don't want to new up and return a tuple object instance for every char that passes through this function, since that seems like a lot of object creation overhead and future garbage collection.

```
public string Translate(char value, out char newValue)
public void Translate(char value, out char? newCharValue, out string newStringValue)
public void Translate(char value, out bool useChar, out char newCharValue, out string newStringValue)
```

Answer (score 4):

What about always returning a string (of length 0, 1, or many), and always calling `writer.Write(string)`?

Comment: Because it creates a new string for every char of the buffer.  If I am outputting 10,000 characters, do I want my method to create 10,000 string objects?

Comment: I don't see the "new" keyword being used on *strings* in your sample code. have you tested it? does this really happen? I think you'll find that the string literals that you declare in your giant switch are interned. On the other hand (and this is just speculating, you should ALWAYS profile), you probably want to stay away from character arrays because they have no such optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

If you return a string why not use "\u00A9" instead of '\u00A9'.ToString()?

Comment: Yes, that would take better advantage of string interning. +1

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting to use this Translate method stand-alone anywhere, or is it always going to be used for the purpose of writing one stream's data to another? How about passing the writer to the Translate method, and letting it call the appropriate `writer.Write` method?