# Modern C++ : what is the best approach for function returning a status (ok/not ok) and an error (if status not ok)?

Tags: c++, c++11

We can return a tuple

```
std::pair<bool, std::string> fooFunction();
```

but that makes code redundant when creating the return value , and force  callers to handle the tuple (easy with structural binding in c++17)

```
if ( okayCondition)
    return {true, {}}; 
else 
   return { false, "blabla error"};
```

or we can use

```
std::optional<std::string> fooFunction();
```

Which is interesting for existing functions returning bool because mostly the callers would not need update thanks to the std::optional operator bool

```
//Legacy code ok
if (fooFunction())
```

I am aware of an heavier approach, a templated ReturnStatus class that throws in case the caller does not test the return status value.
Is there any other approach ?

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?  Least code?  Most robust?  Fastest? ...?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, answers to this question are going to be primarily based on opinion, rather than fact. As such, this question is not really a good fit for SO. I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: yea closeing is the right choice, where would we be if we needed to have an opinion on things rather than answering questions that 90% of the times could be answered by googling it.

Comment: I recommend passing a status variable, and an error stream parameter.  The status would be an `enum`.  The error stream allows the function to emit a more detailed description of the error.  This is very useful when debugging.

Comment: Question was closed years ago, IMHO this is definitly not opinion based. 
For anyone reading this, C++23 brings the std::expected which is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You could consider returning a [`std::error_code`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code) from your function.

Using this class you can provide a [`std::error_code::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/value) which you can use for error handling and a [`std::error_code::message`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/error_code/message) to display info to the user if there is anything actionable or informative.

Comment: I would consider this for new projects and particularly interesting for API (because caller does not have to handle specific error). 
But I see a big problem with it for  usage with legacy code returning bool value : the bool operator return true if the code is 0 (liker errno indeed), so all the caller logic must be inverted.
And also no way to dynamically create the error message with variable name

Answer (score -3):

The C++ way to do things is to not return a status at all.  If there's an error, throw an exception.  Error codes are so 1980's.

Comment: The standard library takes an opposite approach to this in many cases...

Comment: Exceptions are only for exceptional errors, not for common errors.

Comment: Couple links to relevant holy wars https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99683/which-and-why-do-you-prefer-exceptions-or-return-codes and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849490/c-arguments-for-exceptions-over-return-codes since this tends to be a controversial debate

Comment: @CoryKramer thanks, those links were interesting.