# Image cropping in PHP is producing blank result

Tags: php, image-manipulation, gd, crop

I'm simply trying to crop a JPEG image (no scaling) using PHP. Here is my function, along with the inputs.

```
function cropPicture($imageLoc, $width, $height, $x1, $y1) {
    $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageLoc);
    imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$x1,$y1,$width,$height,$width,$height);
    imagejpeg($newImage,$imageLoc,90);
}
```

When I call it as follows--`cropPicture('image.jpg', 300, 300, 0, 0)`--the function completes properly, but I'm left with a black image that is 300x300 px (in other words, a blank canvas). Am I passing in the wrong arguments?

The image exists and is writeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an addition to sobedai's answer: *Any* of those functions you use in cropPicture() can fail. You have to test the return value of *each and every one*. In case of an error they return false and your function cannot continue (properly).

```
function cropPicture($imageLoc, $width, $height, $x1, $y1) {
  $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  if ( !$newImage ) {
    throw new Exception('imagecreatetruecolor failed');
  }

  $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageLoc);
  if ( !$source ) {
    throw new Exception('imagecreatefromjpeg');
  }

  $rc = imagecopyresampled($newImage,$source,0,0,$x1,$y1,$width,$height,$width,$height);
  if ( !$rc ) {
    throw new Exception('imagecopyresampled');
  }

  $rc = imagejpeg($newImage,$imageLoc,90);
  if ( !$rc ) {
    throw new Exception('imagejpeg');
  }
}
```

edit: You might also be interested in http://docs.php.net/error_get_last. The exception messages in the example script aren't that helpful...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll start coding like that from now on. The problem was in the function calling `cropPicture()`. So for future reference, my code above actually works!

Comment: But please don't throw exceptions _everywhere_ ;-) You can easily overuse them. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744070/why-should-exceptions-be-used-conservatively

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

save the return values for imagecopyresampled and imagejpeg

One of those is not working properly, check which is false and that will narrow it down.

At first glance, I would look at reading and writing permissions first.