# throwing exception from constructor in C++

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I have read several articles here and else where that it is OK to throw exception from constructor. However, I have noticed that it doesn't call destructor of base class or its data members if an exception is thrown from the constructor. Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct C
{
    C() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;  }
    ~C() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};

struct E: public C
{
    C c;
    E() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; throw 4; }
    ~E() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    E e;
}


$ g++ test.cpp; ./a.exe
C
C
E
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

In this case, E's constructor throws an exception but C's destructor as a data member or as a base class is not called. Now if C's destructor performs some cleanup operation like closing files/sockets and deleting heap allocations, this can cause problems.

So my question is why and when is it OK to throw exceptions from constructors.

Comment: Note that if you catch the exception in `main`, the destructors are invoked. See [here](http://ideone.com/nQemT).

Comment: Before you get used to using exceptions, you might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744070/why-should-exceptions-be-used-conservatively) and its related question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you catch the error, the destructor will be run. When an uncaught exception is thrown in C++, the runtime calls [`std::terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate). By default, `std::terminate` calls [`std::abort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) which specifically does not call destructors on the way out.

With this version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct C
{
    C() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;  }
    ~C() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};

struct E: public C
{
    C c;
    E() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; throw 4; }
    ~E() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        E e;
    } catch(...) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get output:

```
C
C
E
~C
~C
```

Comment: thats interesting. I thought C++ would invoke the destructors even if they are not handled.

Answer (score 2):

> I have noticed that it doesn't call destructor of base class or its data members if an exception is thrown from the constructor

Yes, it does.

*However*, since you don't `catch` that exception in the entire program, the program is immediately *terminated*.

If you were to catch the exception somewhere higher up the call stack, then the destructors of base class and members would be invoked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You don't handle the "exception".

```
> cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct C
{
    C() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;  }
    ~C() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};

struct E: public C
{
    C c;
    E() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; throw 4; }
    ~E() { cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        E e;
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        std::cerr << "Handled " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Build and run..

```
> make test
make: `test' is up to date.
> ./test
C
C
E
~C
~C
Handled 4
>
```

Both `C`s destructed and a perfectly normal termination.

Answer (score 1):

```
1) E's constructor catched the exception and ran completly.
   Therefore, its object is created and the distructor is 
   invoked.

struct C
{
    C() {cout <<__FUNCTION__<< endl;}
    ~C() {cout <<__FUNCTION__<< endl;}
};

struct E: public C
{
    C c;
    E() { 
    try {
        cout <<__FUNCTION__<< endl; 
        throw 4;
    }
    catch(int i) {
    cerr<<"int "<<i<<" is catched by "<<__FUNCTION__<<endl;
    }   
}
    ~E() {cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;}
void print(){
    cout<<"obj of class E is created"<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
    try {
       E e;
   e.print();
} 
catch(int i) {
   cerr<<"int "<<i<<" catched by "<<__FUNCTION__<<" function"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
Results:
C::C
C::C
E::E
int 4 is catched by E::E
obj of class E is created
E::~E
C::~C
C::~C
*/

2) E's constructor didn’t catch the exception and ran incompletly.
   In result, its object is not created. Therefore, its distructor
   is not invoked.

struct C
{
    C() {cout <<__FUNCTION__<< endl;}
    ~C() {cout <<__FUNCTION__<< endl;}
};

struct E: public C
{
    C c;
    E() { 
   try {
      cout <<__FUNCTION__<< endl; 
      throw 4;
   }
   catch(float i) {
      cerr<<"int "<<i<<" is catched by "<<__FUNCTION__<<endl;
   }    
}
    ~E() {cout << __FUNCTION__ << endl;}
void print(){
    cout<<"obj of class E is created"<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
    try {
        E e;
    e.print();
} 
catch(int i) {
   cerr<<"int "<<i<<" catched by "<<__FUNCTION__<<" function"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
Results:
C::C
C::C
E::E
C::~C
C::~C
int 4 catched by main function
*/
```